# stop gulp from changing shell/cmd title name

Tags: batch-file, cmd, gulp

When gulp is called the it changes my cmd (windows) title to: "gulp"

I want the window name to stay as it was

I know I can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-shell
but this seems like an overkill

I mean that if I call batch script

```
title mytitle
gulp .
```

the window's title is "gulp" and not "mytitle"

Comment: Your problem is unclear. You aren't able to kill a window with the title `gulp` by name? But obviously you know the name. What have you tried?

Comment: @jeb rephrased my question

Comment: Okay, but why you don't kill it with the new name?

Comment: Got 10 gulps running

Comment: Then you could search for the process id before you start gulp. Then you can kill it later by this pid

Comment: Put `title mytitle` (again) *after* `gulp .`, then `mytitle` becomes restored...

Comment: Is there seriously no way to override this behaviour of `gulp`?  I was ecstatic to _finally_ discover this StackOverflow question, but there aren't any answers! D:

Comment: So you have not tried using the START command with its TITLE option.

Comment: Using start with a title does NOT resolve this issue.  While it does set the title of the window (DOS), as soon as gulp runs, the title is changed to just "gulp" but then restored as soon as gulp is finished.  I have gulp processes that I want to kill my window title, but they are all gulp and I only want to kill some of them.

As a side note, there is an issue for this:  https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-cli/issues/64

Comment: I tried using gitbash also, that did not work either.  I tried adding a "start": "title", to package.json, still no dice.  title mytitle (again) after gulp . does nto work if you are doing a -watch because the gulp never ends (obviously).

Answer (score 2):

Use `process.title` as stated in this issue : [concat process.title instead of overwrite](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-cli/issues/64). You shoud use `process.cwd()` to get the directory where the gulpfile is running.

somewhere in your gulpfile, according to your need, write:

```
process.title = process.cwd();
```